# Qt creator : how to display function name as a string in qDebug

Tags: c++, qt

In the header file:

```
#define PRINTTCNAME(tcName)\
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;   // error
#define RUNTC( tc)\
        PRINTTCNAME(tc);\
        res = tc();\
         if(res == false){ \
          TC_clean(); \      
        }
```

in the main.cpp :

```
int TC1_Send();
int TC2_Receive();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    RUNTC(TC1_Send);
    RUNTC(TC2_Receive);
}
```

Problem: if I use above code, it will print the function name of `int main(int, char**)` which is not what I want.
I want to print the name of the test case, e.g. `TC1_Send`,
`TC2_Receive`..

How do I proceed this ?

Comment: question: why you don't use QtTestLib if this is test code?

Comment: @MarekR: this is not a Qt code. The OP just uses QtCreator for this, but if you take a careful look at the code, you can see it is standard C/C++.

Comment: `qDebug` in macro proves that it is Qt code! Anyway QtTestLib works quite well when testing none Qt code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main confusion of yours is that you think this should be a function what you are doing.

It is not. The macro is going through the preprocessor step when its content is put where the "invokation" is happening.

In that context after the preprocessor execution, this function around the code will be the main, so this is an expected behavior.

In this particular case, just use the following:

```
#define PRINTTCNAME(tcName)\
    qDebug() << #tcName"()";   // no error
```

The output will be:

```
TC1_Send()
TC2_Receive()
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. the #tcName works in my case. But one question, does #tcName take out the current function name instead of main ?

Comment: @Heidi: what do you mean by current function name? It will take whatever you pass to it through your nested macro call.

Answer (score 1):

Use `__FUNCTION__` instead of `Q_FUNC_INFO, it works well for me.

Correct use :

```
#define NAME __FUNCTION__

void test()
{
    qDebug() << NAME;
}


int main()
{
    qDebug() << NAME;
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be :

> main
>
> test

[image: proof]

Your code should be :

In the header file:

```
#include <QDebug>

#define PRINTTCNAME(tcName) qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
void RUNTC(int tc)
{
        PRINTTCNAME(tc);
        res = tc();
        if(res == false)
            TC_clean();  
}
```

## main.cpp

```
int TC1_Send;
int TC2_Receive;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    RUNTC(TC1_Send);
    RUNTC(TC2_Receive);
}
```

Comment: I think the result will be the same.

Comment: @vahancho This is what I use every days for my debug, if it doesn't work, provide the message error, I'll be glad to help you !

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx : `__FUNCTION__` will still print 'main(int, char**)', but Heidi wants to print something different.

Comment: as you define it on a #DEFINE, it will take the name of the function where you use the macro. Adding an example

Comment: @Samoth  the result is the same.     Q_FUNC_INFO     prints     int main(int char**)     while                             __FUNCTION__     prints main  only..

Comment: The issue is coming from the definition of the functions

Comment: I agree with @vahancho. This does not address the issue, but I do not understand why Heidi thinks a macro like is a function...

Comment: @LaszloPapp to me, the problem is the way he declares the function `RUNTC`

Comment: @Samoth  I have checked the code, it looks like the reason to define RUNTC like this is to use RUNTC as a test framework.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I am new to c++, didn't do much about define general functions using macros.

Answer (score 1):

I use: -

```
  __func__
```

with this at the top of most functions: -

```
Log(QString("<< %1::%2 >>").arg(metaObject()->className()).arg(__func__));
```

Where the Log function calls qDebug, but could equally output to other locations, such as file, or system logs.

The metaObject()->className() returns the name of the class, so you'd use it if you're using a class function.

Comment: @Heidi, I can see that , but added it for a more complete answer. This is why I stated "iF you're using a class"

Comment: Merlin069, have you tried that with the original code? I am afraid it prints out the same. I believe the OP just does not know what is being done is not a function. This is my two cents.

Comment: @Merlin069: strange, it does not work on my Linux box. It prints out main, and that is what I would also expect it as a user, personally.